# How to obtain the size of the backbuffer in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl

Is there a standard way, using only OpenGL functions, to obtain the size of the backbuffer, in pixels? The closest I've found is querying the size of the viewport, but I doubt it always matches the backbuffer size. I'm looking for the maximum width and height values I can supply to glReadPixels, for example.

Comment: In OpenGL 3.x/4.x or if ARB_framebuffer_object is supported, you should be able to query that with [glGetRenderbufferParameter](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man3/xhtml/glGetRenderbufferParameter.xml). Otherwise, you'll have few options other than taking the window's dimensions.

Comment: @Damon Smart, but I've just tried it and attempting to obtain a renderbuffer parameter when no renderbuffer is bound causes a GL_INVALID_OPERATION.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The backbuffer is part of the window framebuffer planes set (front color, back color, depth, stencil, etc. depending on what's been configured). Since they all belong together they all have the same dimensions. Since the standard framebuffer is tied to the visible window the accessible part is determined by the window dimensions.

However there's one important thing to be aware of: A window's framebuffer is (or used to be) just a slice of the screen framebuffer. If the window is moved or resized only the offset and the stride of the slice in the screen framebuffer changes. It also means that if the window is (partially) obstructed by another window, the occluded parts of the window don't contribute to the framebuffer. Reading from a framebuffer partially covered by other windows you may end up with either undefined contents there, or the contents of the occluding window.

On modern operating systems windows are rendered into off screen areas which can not be occluded, to support compositing window management.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You say that, in some environments, there isn't a dedicated backbuffer for the rendering window, but rather only a reserved space in the "OS desktop backbuffer"? Doesn't the fact that OpenGL has the likes of glReadPixels imply that the image that's been rendered to the backbuffer should always be readable, even if the window is occluded?

Comment: @Trillian: No. glReadPixels just reads the current content of the part of the framebuffer selected for reading. Since the framebuffer is a property of the window any damages to a windows contents will show up in data read using glReadPixels. In that regard glReadPixels isn't that much different from say BitBlt(...). Any decent OS or graphics system sends messages to a window if its contens are damaged and need to be redrawn. If you want to ensure that rendered contents are not corrupted use a PBuffer or a Framebuffer Object.